# Possible to redefine the SessionID in a ColdFusion session?

Tags: session, coldfusion, variables

I'm trying to redefine the SessionID of a ColdFusion session, is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "redefine" and could you elaborate on what you are ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Wouldn't that be equivalent to creating a new session?

Comment: By redefine I mean, is there a way to reset the SessionID. I'm working on a shopping cart that identifies an order by the SessionId and once an order is processed, I want the user to be able to complete another order. Currently the user can complete and new order, but it has the same order id, making the two orders look like duplicates.

Comment: Yes, SpliFF, but when you destroy a session in ColdFusion, the SessionID does not get destroyed. So I was looked for a way to simply redefine the SessionID variable.

Comment: Something does not sound right here. One would assume orders are off loaded and stored in a database table .. So if an order is already processed, why not just clear or remove the processed items from the cart ?

Comment: @Cody Stewart - It's not a good approach to handling order IDs, but if you absolutely want to do this, check out the first paragraph of my answer below.

Comment: @Leigh the orders are stored in a temp cart then moved to a ordered_items table and a record is also put in the order table. My problem is the Session_ID uniquely identifies the order, so once the order is processed the Session_ID is still active... so if a user makes another purchase it uses the same Session_ID as before.

BTW, this is for a final project for a class, so while Gert's answer will get this job done, I think I'm going to just deal with this problem and see what happens. Getting tired of this semester :)

Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: @Cody Stewart - If you think about it, clearly this statement is not true: "Session_ID uniquely identifies the order" ;) If it were, you probably would not be asking this question. Order _identifiers_ should not be volatile values or ones that may be repeated (like a session id). A better choice might be to use an auto record number from your db table or a uuid. So ultimately, attempting to regenerate the session id is just avoiding the true problem ..

Comment: @Leigh for sure :)... for the sake of this assignment I was just trying to get it finished quick and dirty.

Comment: @Cody Stewart - I know, I know .. but for the record, I am not shopping at your virtual store until you get it fixed :P I do not want my pretend credit card number to end up getting charged for Billy Bob's new big screen tv when all I ordered was one copy of cfwack ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back I rolled my own session IDs (by turning off the session cookies in `CFAPPLICATION` and manually setting the `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` in the cookies). Sure, it was very fast, but it wasn't always working (it worked like 99% of the time, but that's not good enough). You can read up on the details of doing this on Adobe's website: [How to write CFID and CFTOKEN as per-session cookies](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/179/tn_17915.html).

Instead, if you're doing this to make more secure session IDs, you're better of turning on *UUID for CFTokens* in CF Administrator. The generated session ID is way longer and harder to guess/calculate than the traditional session IDs.

Comment: This is a solution to my problem; however, seeing as this is just for a project and will not go live, I'm going to let this slide.. I'm tired of this semester.

Thanks Gert G!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your shopping cart.